# Lock strategy of OpenMP programming in C++ for nested loops

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, nested-loops

Yesterday I tested my program of landscape evolution with a big data set(20 Million nodes), without a doubt the running speed was unacceptable. During debugging I noticed that it was a certain function which slowed the whole system down. So I'd like to add multithreading process to it.

However, the function itself is a nested loop with pointer iterators and I believe some of the data has to be locked during the process.

Basically what I was trying to do is to calculate the contributing area of each node. Contributing area, as suggested by its name, is a product (sum) of of all area from upstream node.

Here is the code of that two functions,

```
for( curnode = nodIter.FirstP(); nodIter.IsActive();
    curnode = nodIter.NextP() )  //iterating thru a linked-list of pointers to active stream nodes (*IsActive* returns a  bool value)
{
  CalcDRArea( curnode, curnode->getVArea() ); //calls another function and pass a pointer to current node  as well as a value of its VArea
}
```

---

```
void CalcDRArea( NodeClass *curnode, double addedArea )
{
  // As long as the current node is neither a boundary nor non-valid, add
  // _addedArea_ to its total drainage area and advance to the next node downstream

  while( (curnode->ReachBoundary() == NonBoundary) &&
        (curnode->valid()!=Nonvalid) )
  {
       curnode->AddDrArea( addedArea );  //*AddDrArea* is a simple inline function *`"drarea +=value"`*

    curnode = curnode->getDownStreammNeighbor();      // *getDownstrmNbr()* reruns a pointer to the downstream node
  }

}
```

Here is a simple illustration of nodes and their flowing direction

```
A     B     C     D  
   \  |  /        |
E     F     G     H
      |           |
I     Q     K     L
      |        / 
M     N     O     P
//letters are stream nodes and slashes are their flowing directions
```

My plan is to use OpenMP to implement multithreading at the beginning of first function, the *for loop*. Ideally it will create several threads to calculate each node separately.

However, as shown in figure above, a sequent process can handle streams like

```
A-> F -> Q -> N 
B-> F -> Q -> N 
C-> F -> Q -> N
```

easily, but it will definitely cause problem in a multithreading conditions.

From what I've just read from OpenMP's document, *flush* and *lock* might be the right way to do this, but still I am quite clueless right now and there might still be other potential issues within this loops (like gcc ver. of OpenMP doesn't support "!=").

====Update ====== 
There are two kinds of areas: vArea, which is the area of each node; and drArea which is the sum of the area of current node and area from all its upstream nodes.
I was wondering if I can change the current function to this :

```
for( active node iterator）  
{
    if（currentNode.hasDownStreamNode）
    {
       downStreamNode.drArea += currentNode.vArea + currentNode.DrArea;
    }
    CurrentNode.drArea += currentNode.varea;
}
```

Comment: This seems very easily applicable to dynamic programming - using a better algorithm before trying to multithread something is usually not a bad idea. You're basically doing this in O(n^2) instead of O(n).

Comment: could you give me some advices on a better algorithm? I did realize it is a O(n*n) and don't know how to make it simpler. Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how exactly your algorithm works, because it's not clear from the given code, but the basic idea is that `F` has the value of `A+B+C+F`, while Q has the value `A+B+C+F+Q` and so on. So to compute the value of one node you only have to look at the already computed values of all its predecessors *once* instead of iterating through all nodes from each starting node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before worrying about parallelism, you should first pick a better algorithm. Although in this case one actually goes with the other.

You want a dynamic programming solution in O(N) instead of your current O(n^2) approach. The intuition is simple, just call the following method on each of the leaf nodes in your tree:

```
def compute_value(node):
     if node.DrArea != 0: return node.DrArea
     total = node.vArea
     for n in node.upstream_nodes():
          total += compute_value(n)
     node.DrArea = total
     return node.DrArea
```

To see why this is more efficient, let's take a look at your example. At the moment you add the value of A to F, Q and N. Then you do the same for B and for C. So you have 12 add operations. 
The recursive method on the other hand computes the value for A, B and C first, then we compute F from the already known values of A, B and C. Q gets computed from F and so on. So that's only 8 adds. Basically every node only adds its *total* value to all of its children instead of going through the whole subtree and adding only its own value.

For a simple sequential algorithm you can then go ahead and just implement this iteratively using a list of nodes whose predecessors have all been evaluated (so instead of starting from leaves start from the root nodes). The easiest parallel implementation here is to just use a concurrent queue and atomic add operations, although using one normal queue per processor and some work-stealing would probably be a very good idea in practice.